# Comparing two Integers by their divisibility

Tags: ruby

For instance:

`8 >  10 = true`, since 8 is divisible by 2 three times and 10 only once.

How can I compare two integers from any range of numbers? Are the modulo and divide operator capable of doing this task?

Answer (score 4):

Use binary caculate to judge it

```
def devided_by_two(i)
  return i.to_s(2).match(/0*$/).to_s.count('0')
end
```

To make integer divisibility by 2, just transcode it to binary and judge how many zero from end of banary number. The code I provide can be more simple I think.

Comment: Does removing the `return` keyword count as more simple?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are capable. A number is even if, when you divide it by two, the remainder is zero.

Hence, you can use a loop to continuously divide by two until you get an odd number, keeping a count of how many times you did it.

The (pseudo-code) function for assigning a "divisibility by two, continuously" value to a number would be something like:

```
def howManyDivByTwo(x):
    count = 0
    while x % 2 == 0:
        count = count + 1
        x = x / 2             # make sure integer division
    return count
```

That shouldn't be *too* hard to turn into Ruby (or any procedural-type language, really), such as:

```
def howManyDivByTwo(x)
  count = 0
  while x % 2 == 0
    count = count + 1
    x = x / 2
  end
  return count
end

print howManyDivByTwo(4), "\n"
print howManyDivByTwo(10), "\n"
print howManyDivByTwo(11), "\n"
print howManyDivByTwo(65536), "\n"
```

This outputs the correct:

```
2
1
0
16
```

Astute readers will have noticed there's an edge case in that function, you probably *don't* want to try passing zero to it. If it was production code, you'd need to catch that and act intelligently since you can divide zero by two until the cows come home, without ever reaching an odd number.

What value you return for zero depends on needs you haven't specified in detail. Theoretically (mathematically), you should return infinity but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you will likely mess up much of your code if you redefine such basic method. Knowing that, this is how it's done:

```
class Integer
  def <=> other
    me = self
    return 0 if me.zero? and other.zero?
    return -1 if other.zero?
    return 1 if me.zero?
    while me.even? and other.even?
      me /= 2
      other /= 2
    end
    return 0 if me.odd? and other.odd?
    return -1 if me.odd?
    return 1 if other.odd?  # This condition is redundant, but is here for symmetry.
  end
end
```

Comment: Nicely done. Better than calculating a power of two for each number then comparing the powers.